# Simple constraint layout child with max width in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a `TextView` such that it wraps its content until it reaches its max width. Following code kind of achieves that perfectly until it is used in `RecyclerView`. It seems like `TextView` doesn't measure its width again after I change its text in `onBindViewHolder()`.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.72" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

---

However notice how it works fine if I invoke `requestLayout()` on `TextView` in `onBindViewHolder()` below:

**Update:** Following code in `onBindViewHolder()` works too.

```
ConstraintSet().apply {
    clone(holder.parent)
    applyTo(holder.parent)
}
```

parent being `ConstraintLayout`.

[image]

Does anyone understand whats going on here? Is this a bug in `ConstraintLayout`? Invoking `requestLayout()` in `onBindViewHolder()` is a bad practice and I don't want to do that.

Comment: remove ``` app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap" ```  it will take the width as mentioned i.e ``` app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.72" ```

Comment: I want it to wrap first until it reaches max width.

Comment: Put your textview in FrameLayout. And change app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap" to app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
If use "app:layout_constraintWidth_default" without framelayout, you don't have ellipsize

Answer (score 1):

I know its month late, but I recently encountered this problem, and couldn't find an answer either. The changing ConstraintSet() posed by the author works, but always has the question in mind if this is efficient. Another solution is to change `app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"` to `app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` That worked for me, the recyclerView updates the constraint correctly when recycling the view holders

Comment: This works for me. I replace the wrap value to my desired measure value

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and i solve it by using `RelativeLayout` and set property `android:maxWidth` inside the `TextView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewChat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:maxWidth="256dp"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your view is not getting redrawn during the recycling process. Check if you have 
'setHasFixedSize=true' set for the recyclerview. Remove it or make it false. If it still does not work try changing the TextView width to wrap_content instead of 0dp.

Comment: `setHasFixedSize` didn't help. `wrap_content` makes it such that it doesn't respect `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent` when there is too much contact i.e. it expands to take whole screen's width.